# Can not playback video file recorded by gstreamer

Tags: c++, video, visual-studio-2015, gstreamer, mkv

I can not play the video file, previously recorded myself by gstreamer 1.9.

For the moment i have this pipeline:

for video

> appsrc ! video/x-raw format=RGB,width=800,height=400,framerate=24/1 ! jpegenc ! matroskamux ! filesink location=c:\gstreamer\test.mkv

for subtitles (2 tracks)

> appsrc ! text/x-raw format=utf8 ! matroskamux ! filesink location=c:\gstreamer\test.mkv

Pipeline is constructed element by element using *gst_element_factory_make*, and linked using *gst_element_link*.

When i need to stop recording, i call *gst_element_send_event(_pipeline, gst_event_new_eos());*.

And stopping pipeline by *gst_element_set_state(_pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);* only after have *GST_MESSAGE_EOS* event on a bus.

But, when i want to test result file by *gst-validate-1.0*, i have this:

```
C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\bin>gst-validate-1.0 filesrc location=C:\\Video\\test.mkv ! matroskademux name=mux mux.video_0! jpegdec ! autovideosink 
WARNING: no real random source present! 
Starting pipeline 
Pipeline started 
   warning : EOS received without segment event before 
             Detected on <jpegdec0:src>
             Description : A segment event should always be sent before data flow EOS being some kind of data flow, there is no exception in that regard 

     issue : EOS events that are part of the same pipeline 'operation' should have the same seqnum 
             Detected on <mux:video_0>
             Detected on <jpegdec0:sink>
             Description : when events/messages are created from another event/message, they should have their seqnums set to the original event/message seqnum 

  critical : We got an ERROR message on the bus 
             Detected on <pipeline0>



==== Got criticals, Return value set to 18 ==== 
     Critical error Got error: Internal data stream error. -- Debug message: matroska-demux.c(4759): gst_matroska_demux_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstMatro 
skaDemux:mux: 
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4) 

Issues found: 3 
Returning 18 as error where found 
=======> Test FAILED (Return value: 18)
```

I was trying to send end segment event also, but without luck. I don`t see it on a bus.

**Am i doing something wrong in recording or playback?**

**Can you help me to solve my issue, please.**

My source code for recording. It is extraction. Can be some small bugs. Sorry.
Do you also need it code for playback? It is not working at all.

```
class GStreamerRecorder
{

    GstElement* _pipeline = nullptr;
    GstElement* _videoSource = nullptr;
    GstElement* _videoFilter = nullptr;
    GstCaps* _videoFormat = nullptr;
    GstElement* _container = nullptr;
    GstElement* _recorder = nullptr;

void init()
{
    //init gstreamer library
    gst_init(nullptr, nullptr);


    //init papeline
    _pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("VideoRecorder");
    if (!_pipeline){throw 1;}

    //init video source
    _videoSource = gst_element_factory_make("videotestsrc", "VideoFrame");//appsrc videotestsrc
    if (!_videoSource){throw 2;}

    //init video filter
    _videoFilter = gst_element_factory_make("capsfilter", "VideoFilter");
    if (!_videoFilter){throw 2;}

    _videoFormat = gst_caps_new_simple("video/x-raw",
        "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "RGB",
        "width", G_TYPE_INT, 800,
        "height", G_TYPE_INT, 400,
        "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 24, 1,
        NULL);
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(_videoFilter), "caps", _videoFormat, NULL);

    //init video container
    _container = gst_element_factory_make("matroskamux", "Container"); //matroskamux avimux
    if (!_container){throw 3;}

    //init file recording
    _recorder = gst_element_factory_make("filesink", "Recorder");
    if (!_recorder){throw 4;}
    //set file name
    g_object_set(_recorder, "location","c:\\videoid\\gstreamer\\test.mkv", NULL);

    //build the pipeline
    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(_pipeline), _videoSource, _videoFilter, _container, _recorder, NULL);

    //link elemets
    if ((bool)gst_element_link(_videoSource, _videoFilter) != true) { throw 5; }
    if ((bool)gst_element_link(_videoFilter, _container) != true) { throw 5; }
    if ((bool)gst_element_link(_container, _recorder) != true) { throw 5; }

    //start recording
    GstStateChangeReturn status;
    status = gst_element_set_state(_pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    if (status == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE){throw 1;}
}

void AddFrame(GstElement* destination, unsigned char* data, int size, int offset, int duration)
{
    GstBuffer* buffer= gst_buffer_new_allocate(NULL, size, NULL);
    GST_BUFFER_PTS(result) = offset;
    GST_BUFFER_DURATION(result) = duration;

    //fill buffer with data
    gst_buffer_fill(buffer, 0, data, size);

    //push video buffer to file
    GstFlowReturn ret;
    g_signal_emit_by_name(destination, "push-buffer", buffer, &ret);
}

void StopVideoFile()
{
    //register call back function for soft stop
    GstBus* bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus(GST_PIPELINE(_pipeline));
    gst_bus_add_watch(bus, BusCallback, _loop);
    //gst_bus_add_signal_watch(bus);

    //send soft stop signal
    gst_element_send_event(_pipeline, gst_event_new_eos());

    //activate main loop
    g_main_loop_run(_loop);

    //stop recording
    gst_element_set_state(_pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);

    _pipeline = nullptr;
}

int GStreamerRecorder::BusCallback(GstBus* bus, GstMessage* message, void* loop)
{
    switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE(message))
    {
    case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
        break;

    case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:

        g_main_loop_quit((GMainLoop *)loop);

        return false;

        break;

    }
    return TRUE;
}
};
```

Result of gst-discoverer-1.0 -v C:\Video\test.mkv is

```
Analyzing file:///C://video//test.mkv
Done discovering file:///C://video//test.mkv

Topology:
  container: video/x-matroska
    subtitles: text/x-raw, format=(string)pango-markup
      Tags:
        container format: Matroska
        language code: en

      Codec:
        text/x-raw, format=(string)pango-markup
      Additional info:
        None
      Stream ID: b4368b8a0fa3b45cffd297ed75944d7e99b0c7abc7e93a406c4ee970c8d97ac5/003:16476197871654839755
      Language: en
    subtitles: text/x-raw, format=(string)pango-markup
      Tags:
        container format: Matroska
        language code: en

      Codec:
        text/x-raw, format=(string)pango-markup
      Additional info:
        None
      Stream ID: b4368b8a0fa3b45cffd297ed75944d7e99b0c7abc7e93a406c4ee970c8d97ac5/002:17212272217086422368
      Language: en
    video: image/jpeg, framerate=(fraction)4/1, width=(int)900, height=(int)800
      Tags:
        container format: Matroska
        video codec: Motion JPEG

      Codec:
        image/jpeg, framerate=(fraction)4/1, width=(int)900, height=(int)800
      Additional info:
        None
      Stream ID: b4368b8a0fa3b45cffd297ed75944d7e99b0c7abc7e93a406c4ee970c8d97ac5/001:380798365750797811
      Width: 900
      Height: 800
      Depth: 24
      Frame rate: 4/1
      Pixel aspect ratio: 1/1
      Interlaced: false
      Bitrate: 0
      Max bitrate: 0

Properties:
  Duration: 0:00:38.250000000
  Seekable: yes
  Tags: 
      container format: Matroska
      language code: en
      video codec: Motion JPEG
```

Comment: Please mention which gstreamer version this is. I don't see any obvious mistake. The only questionable approach is to run a custom event-loop to wait for the EOS. Can you run "gst-discoverer-1.0 -v C:\\Video\\test.mkv" to see what ended up in the video. Also to answer one question, you don't need to manually send a newsegment when doing playback. I can only imagine that the created file is not good.

Comment: @ensonic Thank for reaction. gstreamer is 1.9. Also i did try with 1.8 with the same result. Result of discover in question. Event loop is not a goal. It is a better way to do it? I am not sending newsegment when playback. I am not so far for the moment. My try is to send it during recording, because of message i have from validation.

Comment: @ensonic a bit more info for you: i can play this video in VLC, but not in windows media player

Comment: The discoverer output shows that the video is not completely borked. I'd suggest to file a bug for gstreamer, ideally make a short video available. I am suspecting that the muxed video is not proper and VLC manages to skip over that issue. You could also rerun your code with GST_DEBUG="*:3" to see if there are FIXME or WARNINGS that could be helpful.

Comment: @ensonic what do you mean in "not completely borked"? It is something i can try to fix myself? Or i need to wait for bug fix? Sorry, but my level of gstreamer knkwlage is not height enough to recompile gstreamer with GST_DEBUG. Do you have "debug" library available?

Comment: The gst-discoverer output shows that the container structure looks okay. But since you can't play the files (btw. did you try to just use totem) there seems to be an issue. gst-debug is usually not compiled out, so this should still work. Anyway a bug report + the file would be great. Also please fix the typo in the title.